# React - do I need Flux/Redux at this point? (communication between components)

Tags: reactjs

I'm at a point in my app that has me a bit stumped, and I'm not totally sure what to do.

Basically, I have a component structure like this:

```
Layout
  FilePage
    FileDrop
  BackgroundActivity
    UploadQueue
      FileUpload
```

So on every single page, the `BackgroundActivity` component is there, which will show files currently being uploaded. Each `FileUpload` is basically a progress meter and a filename.

The issue here is, when a user drops a file on `FileDrop`, I need that to somehow send file info to `UploadQueue` to create a new `FileUpload`, e.g.:

```
UploadQueue = React.createClass({
  propTypes: {
    fileList: React.PropTypes.any.isRequired
  },

  statusChange(status) {
    debugMode && console.info('[UploadQueue] Status change! %o', status);
  },

  render() {
    let files = [];

    // Convert to a true array
    for (let i = 0; i < this.props.fileList.length; ++i) {
      files = files.concat(this.props.fileList[i]);
    }

    return (
      <div>
        {files.map(file => {
          return <FileUpload key={file.name}
                             name={file.name}
                             statusChange={this.statusChange} />
        })}
      </div>
    )
  }
});
```

It seems that I'd have to pass a callback from `Layout` down to `FilePage`, down to `FileDrop`, so that `FileDrop` can pass file information back upwards to `Layout` which would then send it down to `BackgroundActivity` to pass to `UploadQueue`. This seems like a messy way to connect grandchildren.

Am I at a point where I need Flux or Redux? I know that those frameworks claim to reduce complexity, but looking at Redux examples, it seems to just add *more* complexity. Or is passing functions down several levels just the way things are done in React?

Comment: You might look at https://github.com/reflux/refluxjs. I find it adds clarity to data handling. An example for using reflux is at https://github.com/calitek/ReactPatterns. Look at React.13/ReFluxWebSocket.

Comment: I'd recommend going with redux over other options, having just changed from reflux, slightly more difficult to learn, but worth it, and even facebook have now adopted it internally

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you might be ready for flux/a store, but you can do this without one.
Just treat `<Layout>` as your command center. Define your state (including `fileList`) and actions (including `addFileToList` or whatever) here.

```
// in Layout
...
this.state = {fileList: []}
...
this.myActions = {
    addToFileList: (file) => {
        //add to the fileList with setState
    }
}
```

Pass these actions and state down into the child components.

```
<FilePage data={this.state} actions={this.myActions} />

<BackgroundActivity data={this.state} actions={this.myActions} />
```

You can pass everything down from one component to another like so

```
// in FilePage
<FileDrop {...this.props} />
```

So your data and actions are available in all components. (this is a good starting point, but you might want to refine it a little once everything is working)

Then in `<FileDrop>` call that action:

```
onChange(e) {
    const myFile = // do some things
    this.props.myActions.addToFileList(myFile); //goes all the way up to <Layout>
}
```

Even if you did have a store, it would still be best to keep only one component connected to that store, so you would be passing actions just the same. You would be binding the store to props on `Layout` though and passing that down (rather than state).

The pattern is the same.

Answer (score 0):

As far as React is concerned, both of the following approaches are just fine, ie. :

- Some people pass functions and props down to children
- Some others use a flux(y) architecture (redux, flux, mobx ...)

Answering your questions:

**Am I at a point where I need flux ?**

Flux is not required as such to build an application, however most developers just include it because the state of any significant application will sooner or later go out of control.

**I know that those frameworks claim to reduce complexity, but looking at Redux examples, it seems to just add more complexity.**

At first, it is a little overwhelming, but once you've built a significant sized application without redux and you shift, you'd most probably love to work with redux. It just feels a little complex but makes much sense and is very easy once it enters your muscle memory.

Also, the javascript community is fatigued with new packages and its followers everyday. Redux+React has acquired a strong fanbase, so much so that it has become the almost defacto standard of building react applications. But this does not mean that it is absolutely required.

If this is a project where you can afford to go slow, then you can simply go ahead with passing down props. There is nothing technically wrong in that approach. In fact that is how react was built. Later you can try implementing redux when you face problems like sharing state between components, having a single source of truth etc.

This article by Dan Abramov(The author of redux might be of help too) : [You might not need redux](https://medium.com/@dan_abramov/you-might-not-need-redux-be46360cf367)